# How can I create a private merge request template with GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

Is it possible to create a merge request template for me and only me?

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html) it is possible to create a merge template for a repository but I want a template just for me and only me. My team does not see the need for comment and merge templates. I think they are real time saver. I would like to demonstrate their value by using them on my merge requests.

Comment: Git knows nothing about pull requests or merge requests. They're features of Git hostings so they cannot be configured with Git.

Comment: Hence my reference to GitLab not Git....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is impossible to configure a GitLab repository to use merge request templates which are stored outside of the repository. It is also impossible to create personal templates - all templates stored in the `.gitlab/merge_request_templates/` folder will be available to all merge request authors.

But if you create a template in the `.gitlab/merge_request_templates/` folder and name it something other than [Default.md](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) - then it will not be used by default and you will have to select the template from the dropbox while creating the merge request. So it shouldn't annoy your colleagues and they will still be able to test the template.

Comment: Thanks this is probably about as close as I am going to get for now. I also put in a feature request for Gitlab to add personal templates.